# Multiple mains in c++

Tags: c++

I moved from java to cpp recently. In Java, you can have driver main to test function inside each class. How can I achieve the same thing in C++, since my compiler doesn't allow multiple main in the project?

Comment: Even in Java, you should be using a proper testing framework. "Manually run `main` on every class" is not a testing framework; it's a hack. I've seen Java programs that have a handful of `main` methods (i.e. 2 or 3) for reasonable distinct entrypoints to the application, but never one where *every* class had a `main` that drove tests.

Comment: The C++ standard only allows a program to have one entry function named `main()`, which is not a member of any class.    You can change the `main()` function in your build process by linking in a different object file (which contains the compiled `main()` function) but cannot have two `main()` functions simultaneously within a single program.

Comment: You can have as many `main`s as you like as long as you only link one of them. That doesn't replace a proper testing setup of course.

Comment: there are many different ways to make a test framework.  You could define a specific function in each class that is removed in the release by a preprocessor directive.  You could make a separate file associated with each .cpp specifically to test that and automatically generate your main to run each one with a script.  you could do the same and make a test executable per cpp and script calling those.

Comment: I would first create a static lib with all your functions in it (and put all public header files in a seperate directory). Then I would write a test executable (google-test framework is nice) and a seperate production executable both linking that same static lib.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just your compiler that doesn't allow it, it's the way this language works. To achieve what you are used from Java, simply name your functions something different from `main`, then call them one by one from the `main` function:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

void main_foo(void) {
    cout << "main_foo called";
}

void main_bar(void) {
    cout << "main_bar called";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "main called";
    main_foo();
    main_bar();
}
```

(Untested, just to give you an idea)

Answer (score 0):

You either set up a testing framework like [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) or [Google Test](https://google.github.io/googletest/), or provide a custom `test`-like functions that suit your needs, because C++ does not allow multiple `main()` functions like Java does.